# Center svg icon inside button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I'm currently facing the problem, that the icon inside my button won't center vertically. Somehow the svg also seems to be sticking outside of the span surrounding it. How can I fix this?
This is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button"
 id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      XS
      <div class="select-arrow-icon">
           {% sw_icon 'arrow-down' %}
      </div>
</button>
```

[image]

Comment: You want to center vertically and horizontally or just vertically?

Comment: @JacobPhilpott Only vertically, it's supposed to stay on the right hand side but at the same level as the text

Comment: Try to follow the CSS standards and write `dropdown-menu-button` for the id instead of `dropdownMenuButton`.

Answer (score 3):

I would try using the CSS `flex` property.

Add this style to the parent div element:

```
#dropdownMenuButton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't change the position of the svg, it's still in the same place

Comment: Hmm.. could you post the CSS that you are using too? Maybe another property is overriding it.. cuz i'm pretty sure the best approach to vertical alignment is with a flex box.

Comment: I added a height auf 0px to the surrounding div and it's working. But is this proper practice to just add 0px?

Comment: I'm not sure why you needed to add 0px.. I would need to see all of the CSS but using a flex box is definitely best approach for vertical alignment.

Comment: `align-items` will center it on the off-axis. That is, it will center it only vertically (since `flex-direction` is `row` by default). You also need `justify-content: center` to center it horizontally (across the primary axis)